# "Open in the Stack Overflow app" banner can't be dismissed

Tags: feature-request

Please could you either make the banner dismissible or use the Apple provided [Smart Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)? (I guess there is a reason this isn't being used).

The permanent banner displayed on every page is irritating.

[image]

I know it's hard to make out without a red circle but I'm using my phone to post this :(

Comment: It is irritating, and surely once I have dismissed it once (it seems to be dismissable on Android but keeps coming back) that shows that I have read, and rejected the suggestion. Or perhaps this is an intentional "nag message" to try and force us onto the app? Some businesses do that, but I don't see Stack Overflow as being that type of business.

Comment: I can help you out with that circle if you'd like...

Comment: Or don't nag _at all_ and just let users make their own decisions with their brains...

Comment: I think it’s a built-in iOS feature, like the regular app banner. Since the SO app is linked to https://stackoverflow.com, it allows you to view the content in the app.

Comment: There's no freehand circle...there's no circle! How am I supposed to see the issue? :P

Comment: I also prefer using the web site rather than the app, and having that as a banner is a nuisance. It should be dismiss-able, and once dismissed, permanently replaced by some menu item in the footer or somewhere else not that intrusive and space consuming.

Comment: For people who are looking for details - http://imgur.com/a/L8fOF

Comment: @Mr.Alien The relevant detail is the entire banner, not only its "OPEN" link.

Comment: @Gerry I don't wanna make a huge hand drawn circle, it will mess up my perfection